# Create Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

If the web page contains a link to a particular file format(eg. txt) and user clicks on it. Instead of downloading it must run chrome extension. Does the "matches" in content-scripts be used to match a particular file format or I need to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: Matches applies to page urls, not subresources.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (and perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), and [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Depending on what you plan to do with the link in the extension, there are several possible approaches so it would make sense to describe the goal in the question.

Comment: My plugin should execute its functionality only when I click on a certain file format. I found fileBrowserHandler which can be used to handle any particular extension.